# In Git, if I merge branch B into A and resolve merge conflicts, can merge conflicts still arise when merging A into B again?

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch `integration` which, if I try to merge a branch very similar to `master` into it, gives a large number of merge conflicts. However, I've been told that `integration` has itself been merged into `master`. Does this imply that I should not expect any merge conflicts when merging `master` into `integration`?

Comment: Incidentally, in this case, I wanted to keep the `master` version when conflicts arose, which I did by using `git merge --strategy recursive -X theirs master` from `integration`. This gave rise to far fewer merge conflicts (only a couple `deleted by them` ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is right. If you have merged `integration` into `master`, merging the other way round is just a fast-forward merge. Therefore, the `integration` *branch pointer* can just be moved onto the merge commit and therefore `master` and `integration` point to the same commit.

This is true only if there occur no more commits on one of these branches between the two merges. Otherwise, new merge conflicts are possible.

But you can not derive any assumptions for the branch *similar to `master`* from this.

Answer (score 3):

First, be careful with this general idea, which can produce what version control systems (not just Git) call a *criss-cross merge:*

```
...--o--o---M   <-- br1
         \ /
          X
         / \
...--o--o---N   <-- br2
```

These are not fundamentally *wrong* in any theoretical sense, but they give rise to an ambiguity for later merging: there is (sometimes) no longer a single commit that serves as the merge base for later merges, because both merge results `M` and `N` may be suitable as merge bases.  (Git's standard solution to this problem, with `-s recursive` which is the default, is to first merge the merge bases, then use the result as a new merge base for the two branch tips.)

---

What you're saying in text is perhaps instead:

```
...--o--o--M   <-- master
          / \
...---o--o---N   <-- integration
```

which is rather different—and as [TobiasMende answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51311959/1256452), Git will sometimes do a *fast-forward* instead of merging, unless you prohibit it to force a true merge.  (The diagram above assumes you have run `git merge --no-ff master` while on `integration`.)

Unfortunately, what you have actually said in text is ambiguous:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master
       ?
...---o--o   <-- integration
          \
           \
            M   <-- [proposed merge that gets conflicts]
           /
          /
...---o--o   <-- thirdbranch
```

Here the question mark covers the statement: *I've been told that `integration` has itself been merged into `master`*.  We don't know if this is true, and if it *is* true, we don't know at what point, nor where the merge base was for this merge.  The `thirdbranch` label covers the phrase: *a branch very similar to `master`*.  We don't know *how* similar, or what commits or on it, or where *that* branch has a common merge base with `master` and/or with `integration`.

Determining how a merge will go requires knowing:

- where the merge base is, in the commit graph (or at least, which commit it is); and
- what the two branch tip commits are.

Git will diff the merge base twice: once against the current (HEAD) commit branch tip, to see what *you* changed since the merge base, and then a second diff against the other branch tip, to see what *they* changed since the merge base.  Git then *combines* these two sets of changes, applying those to the files in the merge base.  Applying the combined change to the merge base produces the merge result (as a tree).  Git then makes a new *merge commit*, with both merge tips as the two parents of the merge commit.

The merge result depends on the merge base and these two diffs.